# jQuery animate not working on safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate

I have this jQuery code which animates a div.
It works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but in safari it doesn't move, it is just rotating, and in internet explorer it moves without rotating!
any idea on solving this is appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=0px',
    'left':'+=0px',
    rotate:-50
    }, 500, 'swing');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=35px',
    'left':'+=590px',
    rotate:-60
    }, 7000, 'easeOutQuart');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=0px',
    'left':'+=0px',
    rotate:25
    }, 2000, 'swing');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'+=30px',
    'left':'+=10px',
    rotate:20
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutCubic');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=0px',
    'left':'+=0px',
    rotate:10
    }, 1000, 'swing');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'+=270px',
    'left':'+=180px',
    rotate:0
    }, 5000, 'easeInOutCubic');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=0px',
    'left':'+=0px',
    rotate:-130
    }, 1000, 'swing');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=490px',
    'left':'+=60px',
    rotate:-120
    }, 5000, 'easeInOutCubic');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'-=0px',
    'left':'+=0px',
    rotate:-250
    }, 1000, 'swing');

  $(".plane").animate({
    'top':'+=150px',
    'left':'-=200px',
    rotate:-270
    }, 5000, 'easeInOutCubic');





 });
```

CSS:

```
.plane {
background-image:url('ab.png');
position:absolute;
width:48px;
height:48px;
top:400px;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: and the (rotate) plugin you use is... ?

Comment: Rotate is working fine on safari, problem is with moving the object.

Comment: I don't know what rotate plugin you use, but open this in Safari. Works for me: http://jsbin.com/inozeh/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered by the OP in an edit to the question. Transcribed here as a community wiki answer - even though its a bit terse. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Well after more than 200 views and no answer , I found the solution, I'll put it here for those who faced the same problem. You need to change position of your element to "relative".

Comment: Adding to [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9) notes— By element he means the element that is tied to the `.animate` method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i removed overflow-x:hidden..

```
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to

```
 html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```