# jQuery animate() ignores duration on firefox

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-animate

I'm pretty new to jQuery; I got an **absolute centering** class (it works as I want):

```
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#logo {
    background: url(logo.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    width: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

applied to a Span:

```
<a href="#" id="intro">
  <span alt="" class="Absolute-Center" id="logo"></span>
</a>
```

Then I try to animate it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#intro").click(function() {
    $(".Absolute-Center").animate({
      bottom: "+=80%"
    }, 3000 );
  });
});
```

But the duration of 3000 is ignored, the span moves instantly from one place to another. What am I doing wrong? I suppose there is some kind of problem with the span being inside the a and so many classes and ids, but I don't get it.

With *bottom: "80%"* doesn't work either.

Update: It seems to work in Chrome and IE 11 but not in Firefox 28.

**Update: In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoePerkins/g6vRH/) you can see the problem reduced to its minimum expression.** If you delete the top:0; the animation works ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Works perfectly fine: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nahedule/1/edit)

Comment: Seems to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/6kZPT/

Comment: @Joe - Please confirm that both the jsbin/jsfiddle solutions either work or don't

Comment: doesn't work in firefox, pops up like Joe mentioned

Comment: Uhm, that's right, it actually works in Chrome but not in Firefox. What's happening?

Comment: I figured its something to do with the height of the window, it does work if you open @VtoCorleone's fiddle and make the window smaller, perhaps you need a wrapper or something for this element, I was able to make it work a bit with a wrapper but not the entire body, take a look 

http://jsfiddle.net/6kZPT/2/

Comment: Yep, similar here, when I open the developer tools (thus the window is smaller) it works in FF as well.

Comment: Weird, I see what you mean. If I add another span with fixed position and apply the same animation it works, maybe because of being outside of the normal flow?

Comment: It seems to be related with the height of the window only, when it's less than 400px it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should work? You're browser should be fine, using the "16.0
5.0 -moz-"?

Try adding the prefix "-webkit-"
Check out this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1

Animation info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: I don't understand, I'm talking about a jQuery animation, not a CSS3 one. Anyway, maybe there is a workaround here, I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: of course! here's i better link then: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Comment: And as with little more search I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254782/jquery-animate-not-working-on-safari


TL;DR: change the absolute position to relative

Comment: That's not a solution, if I change it to relative the centered position is lost; and it works in other browsers, there has to be something else...

Comment: if you can live with having the block in the flow and use the relative, enclose is with a <div align="center"> tag?